# Most recent date row with two unique IDS

Tags: sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to create a query that will pull the most recent row for a state and tier3ID combination, while also showing the other three columns.

```
EFFECTIVE_DATE|STATE|ELIGIBLE|INTONLY|AOPELIGIBLE|TIER3ID
01-JAN-05     | AK  | Yes    | No    | No        |1101
15-NOV-12     | IN  | Yes    | No    | No        |1101
01-JAN-05     | AZ  | Yes    | No    | No        |1101
```

Everything I have tries gets me the data combinations, but I cant display the other three rows unless I group by them as well.

I basically want:

```
select state, tier3id, eligible,
max(effective_date)
from thirdtiereligibilityeq
group by state, tier3id, eligible
```

While having eligible, into only, and `AOPeligible` displaying for those rows as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Comment: I added the `greatest-n-per-group` tag.  This question has been answered 500 times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The solution depends on which RDBMS you use. You neglected to mention that crucial detail. For PostgreSQL look at [SQL: Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3800551/939860)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dace9/1 @user1837256

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM thirdtiereligibilityeq T
INNER JOIN (SELECT T2.state
                  ,T2.tier3id
                  ,MAX(T2.effective_date) AS [last_effective_date]
            FROM thirdtiereligibilityeq T2
            GROUP BY T2.state, T2.tier3id) L ON L.state = T.state
                                               AND L.tier3id = T.tier3id
                                               AND L.last_effective_date = T.effective_date
```

Hope this will help you.